# How to write UTF-8 in file instead of hex

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a fairly simple Ruby script which follows the following procedure:

1. Load 500 items from a JSON list
2. Make a GET request for each one of them and process the data
3. If the script exits (for a few reasons) remember the last item processed

The first two are done and they're working fairly well.

My problem is on the third part. In order for my script to remember the last processed, I'm writing it in to a text file:

```
file = File.read('./Formating/Items.json')
last_key = File.open('./last.txt', 'r')
l = last_key.first(1)

data = JSON.parse(file)

puts l
data.each_with_index do |item, index|   

    stuff.do(item)
    last_key.truncate(0)
    last_key.write(index.to_s)

end
```

The problem appears when I'm using the `truncate` command with the `write` command.

Instead of deleting everything from the file and adding the new id as a plain text it adds the new id in HEX.

If I use `truncate` alone it will work. If I use `write` alone it will work. When I'm using them together I'm getting the HEX output.

When I'm reading the file it translates the HEX code to a UTF string and I could leave it like that but, instead of deleting the HEX content, it appends the new id at the end, making the file larger.

Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: `last_key.write(index.to_s)` - does it even work? The file is opened for reading, not writing.

Comment: Please put in the effort to use proper grammar and capitalization. Stack Overflow is a reference book in the making and proper grammar is important.

Comment: When asking about a bug in your code, it *really* helps us help you if you provide the minimal example input and expected output along with a good explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, not what your code is trying to do. Using `truncate` followed by a `write` doesn't make sense so if we understood your goal we could possibly help you with more direct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are truncating the file, that is currently open.

Quick blind untested fix, that must work:

```
file = File.read('./Formating/Items.json')
last_key = File.read('./last.txt').to_i rescue 0

data = JSON.parse(file)

puts "Last key is: #{last_key}"
data.each_with_index do |item, index|
    next if index <= last_key # skip already processed  
    # or: data.drop(last_key).each_with_index do |item, index|
    stuff.do(item)
    File.write('./last.txt', index.to_s)
end
```

Comment: You answer fixed the problem. Thanks alot :)